# iOS Dictionary with two values per key?

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a dictionary that contains 1 value per key.  Is it possible to have 2 values per key?

```
 var data = HomeVC.getData()
 MyVariables.users = data.users;
 MyVariables.img = data.img;

//MY Current dictionary with 1 value and 1 key
   for (index, element) in enumerate(MyVariables.users) 
{
   MyVariables.dictionary[element as! String] = MyVariables.img[index]
}
```

I'm trying to add values from another array to this dictionary.  So in total I would have 3 arrays in the same index position when calling them.  2 values and 1 key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use arrays or tuples as values of a dictionary:

```
var dictionary: Dictionary<String, (ValType1, ValType2)>
dictionary["foo"] = (bar, baz)
println(dictionary["foo"][1])
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of that try saving an `NSArray` as the value for key. The `NSArray` will be able to save more than 1 values and should suffice.

The lifecycle for a 2 values per key would look something like this

```
myDict[@"key1"] = value1;
// then set next value
myDict[@"key1"] = value2;
```

Now your dictionary has lost the first value and you only have access to the last one.

Your code would look something like

```
   for (index, element) in enumerate(MyVariables.users) 
{
   var savedArray: [Your-Object-Type-Here]? = []
   var savedArray = MyVariables.dictionary[element as! String]
   if savedArray != nil {
       savedArray!.append(MyVariables.img[index])
   }
   else {
      savedArray = []
   }
   MyVariables.dictionary[element as! String] = savedArray
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need access to both values at the same time when calling the key

Comment: @DevTonio If you save them in an array, you can. You will call your dictionary for key, and it will return your `NSArray` object. This object will have both the values.

Answer (score 2):

If your values are different types, create a custom class to hold the values.  Make your dictionary keys point to objects of your custom class.